# Use an integer (int) as a pointer argument

Tags: c++11, pointers, int, parameter-passing

If we ignore the aspects:

1. Bad practice
2. Unjustified need
3. and probably others ...

What are the *risks* (*run-time* : crash, undefined behavior, segmentation fault. *implementation-defined behavior* : wrong address generation) of this program as long as the address remains in the interval `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>  

#define TAB_SIZE 2

void UseIntAsAdress (unsigned int  i)
{
    int *pTab =  (int*) i;
    for (int i=0; i< TAB_SIZE; i++)
        cout << "tab ["<<i<<"] = "<< pTab[i] <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int *pTab = new int [TAB_SIZE];
    for ( int i=0; i<TAB_SIZE; i++)
        pTab [i] = i; 

    std::stringstream streamAdr;
    streamAdr << pTab;  
    std::string name = streamAdr.str(); 

    unsigned int i = stoi(name.c_str(), 0, 16);

    UseIntAsAdress (i);

    delete [] pTab;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _risks_?

Comment: @Cubic in wich case thisi program can Crash or produce a segmentation fault, or undefined behaviour, or out of bound for example.

Comment: The primary risk here is that address will not remain in interval `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`... On modern x64 systems it is typically well outside of that range. You should use `::std::uintptr_t` if you want to pass some opaque address around as an integer.

Comment: On 64 bit system `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)`. You will loose upper part of the address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cast a pointer to an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092754/how-do-i-cast-a-pointer-to-an-int)

Comment: The question explicitly asserts that the address fits into `int`. @Landstalker, maybe you can reformulate your question (replace `int` with a bigger integer type, e.g., `intptr_t`) to focus on the actual question?

Comment: @user7860670  @Tarekdakhran, Thanks. Even for unsigned int (`UINT_MAX`) ?

Comment: you can not rely on an unsigned int to be 16 bits. thats one risk

Comment: "If we ignore [the risks], what are the risks?" I think the most egregious issue is the lack of maintainability. "Why did Parva use an `int` here instead of a pointer or a `std::uintptr_t`? What am I missing?"

Comment: @pasbi `unsigned long long` for exemple ?

Comment: @John I agree for hard maintainability. but I'm wondering about the aspects: crash, undefined behavior, segmentation fault, ...

Comment: If you're only interested in potential run-time problems with this code then you need to specify that in the question.

Comment: Casting arbitrary integers to pointers == headache. Don't do that.

Comment: If you can guarantee `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`, then the risks are less (still dependent on implementation defined behavior).  Sign propagation is one possible risk.  If the sizes don't match, its DOA.

Comment: it's more cleare now. Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

Your program has *implementation-defined behavior*. Both the result of `streamAdr << pTab;` and the result of `(int*) i` are *implementation-defined*.

So you need to look at the documentation of your particular compiler to figure out whether this program behaves in the way you expect it to or not.

There is no general guarantee that this will behave correctly.

---

The cast from pointer to integer can be done much simpler as well:

```
reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(pTab)
```

This is assuming your implementation supports `std::intptr_t`. Otherwise (in particular pre-C++11) you can try one one of the standard integer types. Compilation should fail if the type used is too small to hold the pointer values and otherwise it will work the same as `std::intptr_t`.

If then the value resulting from this cast isn't narrowed by conversion to `int`, the result of casting back to `int*` will behave as expected (i.e. you get a pointer to the first element of the array back), otherwise it will still have implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my implementation does not support `std::intptr_t`

Comment: @Landstalker If you are working with some unusual architecture you might want to add that to the question. Also, you can use one of the standard integer types in place of `std::intptr_t`. If the type is too small to hold the pointer values, it should give a compilation error, otherwise it should work the same way I described. But as mentioned above it would be weird for it to not define `std::intptr_t` if such an integer type exists.

Comment: i'm talking about C++ version. i have a usual architecture.

Comment: @Landstalker ok, then try one of the standard integer types as I mentioned above. Also I suggest you add the corresponding C++ version tag to your question, because it is otherwise generally assumed that you have at least C++11 available. What I wrote in my answer otherwise applies pre-C++11 as well.

Comment: I update tag. Thanks.

Comment: @Landstalker You added the C++11 tag, but `std::intptr_t` has been introduced in C++11. If it is not available because of the standard version, you must be using C++98 or C++03.

Comment: I have missed an inlude, i can use `std::intptr_t`. and im on C++11.