# Cast pointer address to int

Tags: c++

Beginner question: How can I take the adress of a pointer and save it as an int?
Example:

```
int *ptr = xyz;
int i = static_cast<int>(ptr);
```

So if ptr points to the memory adress 123, i should be 123. My compiler says it's an `error: invalid static_cast from type 'int*' to type 'int'`.

Guess I am missing something but I don't know what.

Comment: Why would you wanT to do this?

Comment: @JohnDibling interoperation with a poorly written C API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `reinterpret_cast`. An `int` is not guaranteed to be able to losslessly store a pointer though, so you should use the `std::intptr_t` type instead.

Comment: Okay thanks, ofcourse its reinterpret_cast... I tried dynamic_cast but totally forgot about reinterpret_cast. Sometimes I wake up and don't remember my name. Okay I made this one up but seriously, how could I forget that? ;)

I know that pointers and ints can have different sizes but it does not matter for what I do.

Comment: @chris342423: if you are on a 64 bits machine, using `int` means you'll almost never see the real address.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use C-style casting:

```
int *ptr = xyz;
int i = (int) ptr;
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831696/reinterpret-cast-vs-c-style-cast) a nice discussion comparing C-style casting to `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following function to get any pointer as unsigned long. int is not guaranteed to fulfill the task.

```
template <typename T>
static constexpr inline auto ptrToAddr(T *pointer) noexcept
{
  return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(pointer);
}
```

Comment: Unsigned long isn’t guaranteed to work either. As the accepted answer says, this is what uintptr_t is for.

Comment: could you please tell me what is the type of uintptr_t  on your machine?

Comment: It depends on the architecture.