# Save Int Data into Text File in C++

Tags: c++

I working on saving Data into text file and compare it with another text file. Below is the code I worked on:

```
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Data",ios::out | ios :: binary);
    for(x=0; x<100; x++)
    {
       printf("data- %x\n", *(((int*)pImagePool)+x));
       int data =  *(((int*)pImagePool)+x);
       //outfile<<(reinterpret_cast<int *>(data))<<endl;    
       outfile<<(int *)data<<endl;     
    }
```

The result from `printf` is `24011800` and result read from text file is `0x24011800`

Why there is  `0x` appeared? Do we able to remove it?

What is the difference between `reinterpret_cast<int *> & (int *)` but both giving the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"%x" is a specifier for a hexadecimal number. Check this table: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Use "%d" to output a decimal.

EDIT: About the casting, see this:

[Reinterpret_cast vs. C-style cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831696/reinterpret-cast-vs-c-style-cast)

Comment: If you feel this solved your problem, mark it as the correct answer or upvote it so it stays at the top.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you cast it as a pointer, so the output will be a pointer.

Since `data` is a normal value variable, just write it as usual:

```
outfile << data << '\n';
```

---

I also recommend you stop using `printf` when programming C++, there no reason to use it. Instead output using `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << "data- " << *(((int*)pImagePool)+x) << '\n';
```

Or if you want hexadecimal output

```
std::cout << "data- " << std::hex << *(((int*)pImagePool)+x) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example using the ofstream f. The most complicated part are the parameters passed to the open, specifically std::ios::out which specifies the file direction. You could also use std::ios:in for reading from a file along with cin.

```
// ex5.cpp

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "hr_time.hpp"
#include >ios>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    CStopWatch sw;
    sw.startTimer() ;

    std::ofstream f;
    f.open("test.txt",std::ios::out ) ; 
    for (int i=0;i<100000;i++)
    {
      f << "A very long string that is number " << i << std::endl;
    }
    f.close() ;
    sw.stopTimer() ;
    std::cout << "This took " << sw.getElapsedTime() << " seconds" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```