# error: invalid conversion from `void*` to `void (*)()` in case of dlsysm

Tags: c++, c++11, dlopen, dlsym

I am creating sheared object and opening using dlsysm() but I am getting the following error:

> error: invalid conversion from "void*" to "void (*)()"

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<dlfcn.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    void (*fnptr)();
    void *handle;

    handle = dlopen("./libtestshared.so",RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        cerr << "Cannot open library: " << dlerror() << '\n';
    } else {
        cout<<"Opening"<<'\n';
    }

    fnptr = dlsym(handle , "fun");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the code where you get the error? hard to see what is going on here

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        void (*fnptr)();
        void *handle;
        handle = dlopen("./libtestshared.so",RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!handle)
        {
                cerr << "Cannot open library: " << dlerror() << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
                cout<<"Opening"<<'\n';
        }

        fnptr = dlsym(handle , "fun");

        return 0;
}

Comment: ok... i have added the code formatted for you...

Comment: waiting it to be peer reviewed....

Comment: And this is not a C++11 questions... i will propose to retag this

Comment: @Stefano `<iostream>` and namespaces are definitely C++.

Comment: @Stefano also, why did you sneakily modify the code while editing? Your edit had invalidated the question...

Comment: how did i invelidate the question?... if this was done was by mistake...

Comment: oh yes...<iostream> you are right!

Comment: @Stefano look at the edit history. you replaced `void (*fnptr)();` with `void *fnptr;`. And please edit your comments... It's not whatsapp...

Comment: This question comes up quite frequently; a simple solution is: `fnptr = (void (*)())(intptr_t)dlsym(handle , "fun");` Some people will argue this based on the fact that on some platforms code-pointers might be bigger than data-pointers. But on these platforms you cannot use `dlsym` either.

Comment: Added back the C++11 tag, because it's exactly this cast which led to the introduction of "conditionally supported behavior" in C++11.

Answer (score 4):

As `dlsym` can return a pointer to a function of any signature, its designers chose to return an opaque `void*`. Of course, `dlsym` works under the assumption that such a `void*` can then be safely converted to the correct function pointer type. This is done as follows:

```
auto fnptr = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(dlsym(handle , "fun"));
```

Comment: Only, you made the answer C++11 by adding the `auto` keyword ;)

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius What do you mean?

Comment: The `auto` keyword was not added until C++11. Although the TS is probably using a new compiler, older ones will not support it. In the case of the TS, he already defined `fnptr`earlier (c-style ;) ), you could even leave it out in your answer.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius the question was originally tagged [c++11]. In any case, there's no reason for SO answers to be bloated with retrocompatibility with a fifteen-year old standard unless explicitly requested (by using the [c++03] tag).

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius: You need C++11 anyway, because in C++98 this was illegal.

Answer (score 3):

A `void *` is not compatible with a function pointer.

A cast is required in this case:

```
fnptr = (void (*)())dlsym(handle , "fun");
```

Comment: Although correct, this is c-style casting. I think Quentin's answer is better from a C++ perspective. See [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

Comment: when i am calling the fnptr segmentation fault is happened. 0x080487d8 in main () at sampledlopen.cpp:21
        fnptr = 0
        handle = 0xa048020

Comment: @Yugandhar Your fnptr is zero (ie. null) so you're calling a null pointer.

Comment: @JHBonarius Indeed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831696/reinterpret-cast-vs-c-style-cast
However this is still working nicely and provide compatibility with C in this very specific case

Answer (score 0):

I have never used dlsym but here what his [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) says:

> The function dlsym() takes a "handle" of a dynamic library returned by dlopen() and the null-terminated symbol name, **returning the address where that symbol is loaded into memory**.

So what it return is not a function pointer but a standard pointer! Something as follow should work:

```
void* returnedAddress = dlsym(handle , "fun");
fnptr = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(returnedAddress);
```

Comment: This is not what the TS wants: he deletes his own comment, but he expects the returned address to be a function pointer. So the 'undefined' pointer (imho there is no such thing as a "standard" pointer) needs to be cast to the correct type.

Comment: i have modified my code void* returnedAddress = dlsym(handle , "fun");
fnptr = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(returnedAddress); but i am getting segmentation fault. by analyzing core handle=0(i.e #1  0x080487d8 in main () at sampledlopen.cpp:23
        fnptr = 0x8048418
        handle = 0x0
        returnedAddress = 0x82ee020 )